# How does Mission Planner update Parameters List values?

Tags: embedded, serial-communication, arduino-c++, mission-planner

In [Mission Planner](https://ardupilot.org/planner/), when you change any parameter in the parameter list, say RC limits or PID; after pressing 'write parameters' the software *updates* the parameters.

I tried finding how does the same happen but to no avail (I don't know what it's called exactly). How does Mission Planner write parameters to already existing firmware on the [APM board](https://www.ardupilot.co.uk/). Or it rewrites the firmware again with updated parameters?

I want to implement similar kind of procedure. To test with, I have an arduino board running a code. Instead of uploading entire code again and again, there must be a way to just update the value of a variable using some protocol (Serial) sent from the custom software on the PC. Just like updating a parameter when required. How to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ATMEGA1280 used on the ArduPilotMega has a 4K EEPROM on-chip.  Other MCUs used in Arduinos have EEPROM of varying capacity.  The Arduino library includes support for it:   https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/EEPROM

An EEPROM (Electrically Erasable Programmable Read-Only Memory) is a non-volatile memory technology similar to Flash, but with properties that make it more suited to storage of small amounts of configuration data, such as being byte level re-writable.  It is much less dense (takes up more space) than flash memory, so is less suited to code storage.

Comment: Thanks for your input! So it is like the software updates the EEPROM  ? using  Serial protocol ? So you need a microcontroller in between to write serial data to EEPROM?

Comment: The EEPROM is _in_ the microcontroller (in this case).  You could observe the serial exchange using something like https://freeserialanalyzer.com/, but clearly there will be some protocol whereby the serial data is received by the micro and used to write the EEPROM - but that is not what you asked, otherwise I'd have included that in the answer.  ArduPilot software and hardware is all open source, so you could just take a look.